# ASP.NET Core show login page at startup

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm in the process of learning asp.net core and am building a test web app using razor pages.I have created a login page and want this login page to be the landing page. I'm struggling to figure out how to do this, I've read up on routing and mapping but nothing that shows a step by step that I can follow and uderstand. If anyone can assist me with this or point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
AJ

Comment: Could you provide more details pls? Like the file explorer and login page code.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access an action that requires login first, you can use the following code to set the default login page：

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(x =>
    {
        //When user doesn't login and he access to an action with [Authorize],
        //He will redirect to the loginPath
        
        x.LoginPath = "/your login page path";

        //When user has loged in but the role is not the specified role，
        //He will redicet to the AccessDeniedPath,
        //Then you can custom your own error page in this path.

        x.AccessDeniedPath = "/your AccessDeniedPath";
    });
```

You can follow this [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cookie-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) to create a simple project about `Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET Core without using Identity`